# SKAction plays sound loop with a pause

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Loop is playing fine, except one thing: a little pause between iterations. Code:

```
var bgMusic = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MenuSound.mp3", waitForCompletion: true))
```

Comment: May want to look into using the AVAudioPlayer to play music.

Answer (score 0):

Your pause is probably caused by a silent period at the end of your music/sound file. Use a sound editor app to cut out the dead air at the end of the file.

Comment: I made a sound by myself, so i am sure it is valid

Comment: That's the only reason it could be. You might have a slight pause in the beginning if the asset needs loading but once loaded it will play without delays. Also, using mp3 is not a good idea because it requires hardware assisted decoding. This means that you can ever only play one mp3 at the same time and it requires your hardware to spend time decoding every single time the sound is played. I recommend using a .wav instead. Explained here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW10

Comment: I used caf at the beginning, but something gone wrong :D Thanks for advices.